# ¿Como generar el archivo config/secrets.yml en Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Resulta que acabo de empezar un proyecto en RoR y mi proyecto no contiene el archivo secrets.yml, me gustaria saber como generar uno o hacer aparecer el original que deberia estar oculto en algun lugar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El secret ya no se genera en rails 5 ahora se usa otros archivos, si tu rails es mayor a 5 entonces necesitaras usar el comando `EDITOR="vim" bin/rails credentials:edit` el valor de tu EDITOR puede también ser `nano` depende de cual tengas instalado `EDITOR="nano" bin/rails credentials:edit`.

Si tu rails es menor a 4 entonces aqui te dejo un ejemplo de tu secrets:

```
development:
  secret_key_base: super_long_secret_key_for_development
  active_merchant_login: 896667
  active_merchant_password: supersecretpassword888

test:
  secret_key_base: super_long_secret_key_for_test
  active_merchant_login: 896667
 active_merchant_password: supersecretpassword888

production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
  active_merchant_login: <%= ENV["AM_LOGIN"] %>
  active_merchant_password: <%= ENV["AM_PASSWORD"] %>
```

Lo tome de esta [liga](https://richonrails.com/articles/the-rails-4-1-secrets-yml-file)

Comment: Tienes razon, mi versión rails es la 5.2.1....Deberé de seguir los primeros pasos que describes, pero sabes cual es el archivo que se utiliza?

Comment: Existen 2 archivos uno es credentials.yml.enc y el otro master.key dentro de tu carpeta config.
El primero contiene las llaves encriptadas y el segundo se utiliza para desencriptar y poder editar.

Answer (score 0):

Además, en ambiente de producción debes crear la variable de entorno SECRET_KEY_BASE y asignarle una clave generada por el comando rails secret.

C:>rails secret
175501ea97a18f4f153b0f8df3c10a3ce97f09871bb5eb88c5ae9998b1a089c06bff6f88eb57bc94a8ff1d635ff0fa7a58df108e7e7d10c664f9234862a13714

Answer (score 0):

- Cómo se utilizan las credenciales en Rails 5.2 Ejemplo API Spotify:

  - Para consumir los datos de Spotify es necesario registrar la App que desarrollamos, lo puedes hacer en el siguiente link [Spotify](https://developer.spotify.com/dashboard/login)
  - Al utilizar Ruby on Rails 5.2, tenemos que adicionar los datos de acceso de la app que registramos, al archivo "../config/credentials.yml.enc" osea el «Client ID» y el «Client Secret»
  - Para modificar el archivo "../config/credentials.yml.enc", en la terminal (o línea de comandos) deberemos estar ubicados en el directorio del proyecto y ejecutar el comando `EDITOR=nano rails credentials:edit`, luego añadir los datos del «Client ID» y el «Client Secret»
  - Debería tener un aspecto similar al siguiente

    ```
    development:
      spotify:
       access_key_id: abc123
       secret_access_key: abc123  

    production:
      spotify:
        access_key_id: abc123_
        secret_access_key: abc123_
    ```
  - "../config/master.key" debe ser añadido a ".gitignore" pues el la clave de desencriptación.

Esta respuesta es extraída de otra pregunta, el ejemplo completo con la API de spotyfy esta en este [link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/219257/como-consumir-la-api-de-spotify-en-ruby-on-rails-5-2/220546#220546)

Comment: El ejemplo completo con la API de spotyfy esta en este [link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/219257/como-consumir-la-api-de-spotify-en-ruby-on-rails-5-2/220546#220546 )

Comment: Hola @vifrac, esta respuesta es una copia (parcial) de tu otra respuesta enlazada. Eso no quiere decir que sea incorrecta o que esté mal, pero que las respuestas estén duplicadas parcial o totalmente suele ser una indicación de que algo _no va bien_. Normalmente, aunque no siempre, la pregunta es un duplicado o la respuesta no se ajusta bien a la pregunta. ¿Es éste alguno de esos casos?

Comment: No, no es ningun caso de los que comentas. Simplemente extraje una porción de otra respuesta (de mi propiedad) que creí se ajustaba a la respuesta de la pregunta que se estaba haciendo. He modificado la respuesta a esta pregunta  para que muestre esa información. Gracias por tus comentarios.