# Como consumir la API de Spotify en Ruby on rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby, autenticación

Trabajando con la Spotify-API en Rails

Estoy usando

- Rails 5.2.1.1
- ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]

---

1. A partir de la versión 5.2 de Ruby on Rails, se generaron algunas
   mejoras en los apartados de [seguridad](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#environmental-security).
2. Para conectar la API de Spotify con Rails se sugieren algunos
   Wrappers como lo es [guilhermesad/rspotify](https://github.com/guilhermesad/rspotify)
3. Es necesaria la autenticación de de la aplicación para lograr
   obtener los resultados de las consultas de la API
4. Al probar la API a través de RSspotify en la consola de rails me arroja los siguientes errores. (cada línea es una acción)

---

> `require 'rspotify'`
>
> `RSpotify::Track`
>
> `RSpotify::Track.search('bohemian')`
>
> Me arroja ->>  `RSpotify::MissingAuthentication (RSpotify::MissingAuthentication)`
>
> `RSpotify.authenticate("<spotify_client_id>", "<spotify_client_secret>")`
>
> Me arroja ->> `RestClient::BadRequest (400 Bad Request)`

---

**Mi pregunta es, si me pueden ayudara con lo siguiente**

- Cómo puedo consumir la API de spotify en Ruby on Rails 5.2
- Cómo se utilizan las credenciales en rails para consumir esta API
- Cómo puedo autenticarme desde rails.

**De antemano agradezco la ayuda.**

Comment: Hola vifrac, bienvenido a S.O. en español. Creo que tu pregunta es muy amplia, en general las preguntas aquí son más específicas. Podrías revisar el [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para mejorar tu pregunta. Respecto al 1er error, debe ser porque estás llamando `search` antes de autenticarte. Respecto al 2do error, supongo que los `id/secret` que estás enviando para autenticarte puedan ser incorrectos y por eso spotify responde con un 400.Revisa en https://developer.spotify.com/dashboard/applications tus aplicaciones y que correspondan con lo que pusiste. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, respecto a la amplitud de la pregunta, estoy dando alcance a la informacion que estaban sugiriendo en "como preguntar". Tengo un problema con la forma en que debería consumir la API,  sabes de algun tutorial que me pueda dar luces. He buscado pero no encuentro cual es el inconveniente, por otro lado hasta ahora estoy aprendiendo Rails. Te agradeceria si me puedes orientar de como debería formular la pregunta para que sea mas específica. Y tienes razón con las observaciones de los errores pero no se como autenticarme.

Comment: En la [documentación](https://github.com/guilhermesad/rspotify#rails--oauth) de la gema sale explicado como autenticarse, que es lo que debes hacer primero. En la página que te mandé antes, de aplicaciones de spotify, debes crear una nueva aplicación y luego [copias el id y secret](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bRa0.png) que te muestra para para usarlo como datos de autenticación en rspotify. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracia por la información, ya pude solucionar el problema. En un rato  colocare la forma en como solucione mi inconveniente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mis preguntas eran las siguientes**

- Cómo puedo consumir la API de spotify en Ruby on Rails 5.2:

  - Podemos hacer uso de la gema "[rspotify](https://github.com/guilhermesad/rspotify)" para consumir los datos de Spotify
- Cómo se utilizan las credenciales en rails para consumir esta API:

  - Para consumir los datos de Spotify es necesario registrar la App que desarrollamos, lo puedes hacer en el siguiente link [Spotify](https://developer.spotify.com/dashboard/login)
  - Al utilizar Ruby on Rails 5.2, tenemos que adicionar los datos de acceso de la app que registramos, al archivo "../config/credentials.yml.enc" osea el «Client ID» y el «Client Secret»
  - Para modificar el archivo "../config/credentials.yml.enc", en la terminar (o linea de comandos) deberemos estar ubicados en el directorio del proyecto y ejecutar el comando `EDITOR=nano rails credentials:edit`, luego añadir los datos del «Client ID» y el «Client Secret»
  - Debería tener un aspecto similar al siguiente

    `development:
     spotify:
      access_key_id: abc123
      secret_access_key: abc123`

    `production:
     spotify:
       access_key_id: abc123_
       secret_access_key: abc123_`
  - "../config/master.key" debe ser añadido a "gitignore" pues el la clave de desencriptación
- Cómo puedo autenticarme desde rails.

  - Luego de cargar los datos de acceso al archivo correspondiente (credentials.yml.enc) crearemos variables que nos permita leer esos datos y cargarlos donde creamos necesario.
  - Deberemos tener en cuenta que cuando carguemos la app a a un ambiente de producción, las llaves de desencriptado no se cargarán, por ende debemos cargarlas manualmente o como sugiere la plataforma que utilicemos para tal fin, el siguiente es un video explicativo para la plataforma [heroku](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BHgvPPr2nLE&t=1116s).
  - Las variables tendrían un aspecto similar al siguiente (la tercera línea de este código es la forma como nos autenticamos en Spotify mediante "rspotify")

    `s_id = Rails.application.credentials.development[:spotify][:access_key_id]
    s_secret = Rails.application.credentials.development[:spotify][:secret_access_key]
    RSpotify.authenticate(spotify_client_id.to_s, spotify_client_secret.to_s)`

> **Espero como a mi, tambien esta solución fuere de ayuda para ustedes.**